# How can i cache grpc channels into Redis?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis, grpc, stackexchange.redis

I have a grpc project and I want to send request between multi server with grpc. so, I want to cache grpcChannels to use every times. How can i save grpcChannels into redis with one key?

Cache grpc channel into Redis Database

Comment: Did you try to simple serialised and deserialized it ?

Comment: You can store values into a database, not objects. At least not the way you think you can.

Comment: I wanted to save the list of channels as roundrobin in the redis database, but unfortunately it was stored as null, so I finally used the hash type and saved the list of channels in the redis database. @LeBigCat

Comment: [Hashes](https://redis.io/commands/?group=hash) will work. But you might also want to look at using [Sets](https://redis.io/commands/?group=set).

Comment: Using Hashes is Good but when i cache GrpcChannel in redis, I can't deserialize it.
Exception is "Unable to find a constructor to use for type Grpc.Net.Client.GrpcChannel. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor" 
@GuyRoyse

Comment: I'm just the Redis guy, pun not intended, and this sounds like a problem for a .NET developer. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to store and load a grpc channel from Redis. The main resource of a grpc channel is opened connection(s) to the other side (client/server) which are like file descriptors for your app and that is why it can't be load from redis. But this is not a problem: just reuse a channel as much as possible in your app, i.e., do not close a channel after every RPC call (more on this here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/performance?view=aspnetcore-6.0#reuse-grpc-channels). But it is ok for the app process to create a channel on startup.

Comment: thank you, It's the best answare @YuriGolobokov

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to store and load a grpc channel from Redis. The main resource of a grpc channel is opened connection(s) to the other side (client/server) which are like file descriptors for your app and that is why it can't be load from redis. But this is not a problem: just reuse a channel as much as possible in your app, i.e., do not close a channel after every RPC call (more on this here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/performance?view=aspnetcore-6.0#reuse-grpc-channels). But it is ok for the app process to create a channel on startup

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/performance?view=aspnetcore-6.0) from Microsoft about the best practice for using gRPC. A quote from the doc:

> gRPC clients are created with channels. gRPC clients are lightweight objects and don't need to be cached or reused.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I saved the list of channels in the redis database In order not to create a new channel, It's an Idea but I like to view your comment.

Comment: Make sure not to confuse clients with channels. Channels should be reused, clients not necessary.